# Create a named list of numerics from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, function, tidyverse

I want to create a named list of numerics from my `DATA`, such that all `Variables` ending in `baseline` get subtracted from their corresponding `Variables` ending in `post1`.

For example, the first element's *name* will be `"beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline"`.

For example, the first element's *numerics* will be `c(5,-2)` meaning they are on `Row 5` and `Row 2`.

Is it possible to automate this process to achieve my ***`Desired_output` (below)***?

```
DATA <- read.table(header=TRUE,text =
"
Row           Variables
1     advanced_baseline
2     beginner_baseline
3 intermediate_baseline
4        advanced_post1
5        beginner_post1
6    intermediate_post1
7        advanced_post2
8        beginner_post2
9    intermediate_post2")


Desired_output = 
list("(    beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline    )"= c(5,-2),
     "(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(6,-3),
     "(    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )"= c(4,-1),
     "(    beginner_post2 - beginner_baseline    )"= c(8,-2),
     "(intermediate_post2 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(9,-3),
     "(    advanced_post2 - advanced_baseline    )"= c(7,-1)
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Here is an option for any number of "post" measures:

```r
library(dplyr)

DATA |>
  filter(!endsWith(Variables, "baseline")) |>
  mutate(Variables2 = sub("post\\d+", "baseline", Variables),
         Variables = paste0("(", Variables, " - ", Variables2, ")")) |>
  right_join(filter(DATA, endsWith(Variables, "baseline")), 
             by = c("Variables2" = "Variables"), suffix = c("_post", "_pre")) |>
  summarize(Variables, Row = list(c(Row_post, -Row_pre)), .by = Variables) |>
  tibble::deframe()
# $`(advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline)`
# [1]  4 -1
# 
# $`(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline)`
# [1]  5 -2
# 
# $`(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)`
# [1]  6 -3
# 
# $`(advanced_post2 - advanced_baseline)`
# [1]  7 -1
# 
# $`(beginner_post2 - beginner_baseline)`
# [1]  8 -2
# 
# $`(intermediate_post2 - intermediate_baseline)`
# [1]  9 -3
```

---

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

DATA |> 
  separate_wider_delim(Variables, "_", names = c("x", "y")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = Row, names_glue = "({x}_post1 - {x}_baseline)") |>
  arrange(desc(y)) |>
  mutate(across(-1, \(x) x * c(1, -1)), .keep = "none") |> 
  as.list()
# $`(advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline)`
# [1]  4 -1
# 
# $`(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline)`
# [1]  5 -2
# 
# $`(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)`
# [1]  6 -3
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you (+1)! Just curious, if `post` objects were more, like `post1` and `post2`, ... `postn`, could have modified your code to do the same thing for `post2`, ..., `postn`, as well? In other words, can you make the suffix of `post` to be `1,...n` and do the same thing for each of the `postn` objects?

Comment: You are welcome! That would require some modification of this code to work. Primarily, having a column with the post number and then adding that column name to the `names_from` and `names_glue` arguments.

Comment: Add a pipe to `group_by` before summarize and remove the `.by` argument.